# ajax call async issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, pdf, call

i just have a problem with the async mode. in my ajax call i create a pdf, which takes a while (10 - 45 seconds) and in the success section of ajax i call `window.open('path of pdf')` to show the created pdf.

my issues:

1. When i call the ajax in the sync mode, the function dies in Safari and no popup appears.
   due to, the request tooks too long...
2. When i call it in the async mode, everything is fine but the popup blocker blocks the pdf.
   in the sync mode the popup appears, though the popup blocker is active.

Comment: The timeout issue could be prevented usings the `timeout`option in the ajax call. Besides this, think about using `window.location`to redirect the browser to the pdf instead of opening it. No Pop-Up Blocker will block this.

Answer (score 0):

Check status with `setInterval` method every few second.

- if status is `creating` show preloader
- if status is `rejected` show message about error
- if status is `created` redirect to page that you want

What kind of popup blockers can block popups created by JS/HTML?